# What happens when I change the outerHTML of a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to change the outerHTML of a DOM element like this:

```
var span = document.createElement('span')
document.body.appendChild(span)
```

It becomes:

```
<body>
  <span></span>
<body>
```

And I change its outerHTML:

```
span.outerHTML = '<p></p>'
```

It becomes:

```
<body>
  <p></p>
<body>
```

Then I print it outerHTML:

```
span.outerHTML
```

It prints: `<span></span>`.

I expect it prints `<p></p>` because I changed it. However it doesn't work like my expectation.

Comment: The variable `span` refers to the originally created element, setting `outerHTML` creates a new element.

Comment: The outerHTML attribute of the Element DOM interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants

Comment: The variable referring the original element is also explained in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML#Notes).